# Abstract Class Inheritance & Data Contracts

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-3.5

I have an `abstract class BaseClass` with two attributes I want to share with `class ClassA : BaseClass` and `class ClassB : BaseClass`. However, I want both `ClassA` and `ClassB` to be marked with `DataContractAttribute` in a way that the members inherited from `BaseClass` are also exposed in the contract. However, I don't want `BaseClass` itself to be exposed as a data contract. Is this possible in WCF (.NET 3.5)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, AFAIK that is not possible. Even if you `new` the properties to add data-member markers it'll still complain:

> Type 'BaseClass' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.

Comment: So, if I want to use inheritance for this situation, my only option is to mark `BaseClass` with a `DataContractAttribute`, right?

Comment: I doubt it, I suspect WCF won't be able to serialize (because it can't deserialize) an abstract class.

Comment: @B.M indeed; @BenCr abstract types are often fine as long as a concrete type is resolved at runtime